# Can I inspect flags on a LazyFrame?

Tags: python-polars

Say I do

```py
df = pl.LazyFrame({'a': [date(2020, 1, 1), date(2020, 1, 3), date(2020, 1, 2)]})
df = df.sort('a')
```

If I materialise the frame, I can do

```py
In [31]: df.collect()['a'].flags
Out[31]: {'SORTED_ASC': True, 'SORTED_DESC': False}
```

and see that polars knows `'a'` to be sorted.

But, I suspect polars already knows `'a'` to be sorted, because I just did `.sort('a')`? Is there a way to check the sorted flags on a `LazyFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

Well `a` isn't sorted until you materialize it so it's kind of a catch-22. The query plan includes a sort but it isn't sorted yet.

You can do `df.explain(optimized=True)` and see `'**SORT BY [col("a")]**\n  DF ["a"]; PROJECT */1 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"'`

This probably isn't very reliable because you could have

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [date(2020, 1, 1), date(2020, 1, 3), date(2020, 1, 2)]}).sort('a').lazy()
```

in which case the query plan given by `explain` won't have the sort.

Another example of unreliability is

```
df = pl.LazyFrame({'a': [date(2020, 1, 1), date(2020, 1, 3), date(2020, 1, 2)],
                'b':[2,1,5]})
df=df.sort('a').sort('b')
df.explain(optimized=True)
```

in which case you'd see `SORT BY [col("a")]` but maybe not realize the `b` will win the sort war

or you can use `select` and `head` to only materialize the minimum.

```
df.select('a').head(1).collect()['a'].flags
```